# Python, strptime is skipping zeros in the millisecond section

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, strptime

I want to extract the timestamp from a string, but the milliseconds part is not being read properly

```
datetime.strptime('20130629110924095','%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f')
```

produces the following output

```
datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 29, 11, 9, 24, 95000)
```

instead of

```
datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 29, 11, 9, 24, 95)
```

to be clear: 95 milliseconds

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tried padding with zeros, but it does not help

    datetime.strptime('20130629110924.095000','%Y%m%d%H%M%S.%f')

Comment: `%f` parses microseconds. 95000 microseconds equals 95 milliseconds. So `strptime` is already parsing your string correctly.

Comment: I'm sorry. The error happened when I edited the file in MS Excel. It removed all trailing zeros from the source file!
Did not see that coming!

Answer (score 2):

Microseconds consist of six digits. 95 milliseconds = 95000 microseconds.
So to get datetime with 95 milliseconds like `datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 29, 11, 9, 24, 95000)` write:

```
datetime.strptime('20130629110924095000','%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f')
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the first code also outputs datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 29, 11, 9, 24, 9500)

The answer I'm expecting is datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 29, 11, 9, 24, 95)
I'll correct in the question regarding the second snippet

Comment: I see. But, datetime.strptime('20130629110924000095','%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f') gives me 95 microseconds, instead of 95 milliseconds.

Comment: Solved! Thanks, the issue was in the source file!

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) says:

> %f is an extension to the set of format characters in the C standard (but implemented separately in datetime objects, and therefore always available). When used with the strptime() method, the %f directive accepts from one to six digits and zero pads on the right.

So the result you get is expected behaviour, your '095' is padded to '095000'.

Comment: Thanks!
So, what should I input to get 95 milliseconds as output?
The data is read from a file in which this is written in the format "20130629  1109240  095" "20130629  1109240  195" etc.

Answer (score 1):

`95000` is in microseconds that is equivalent to 95 milliseconds i.e., the input (`'095'`) is already correct if you want to get 95 milliseconds.

Here's the same input with some additional formatting for readability:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime('2013-06-29 11:09:24.095','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 29, 11, 9, 24, 95000)
```

A millisecond is `0.001` seconds and therefore `95` milliseconds is `0.095` seconds that is why `095` is the correct input for `%f` that parses the fractional part of a second.